# AWS Cognito IDP: check whether a user has an MFA device paired

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm currently building 2FA functionality into a website.

The authentication back-end is AWS Cognito IDP.

I see how I can pair the device, some pseudo code below.

```
# 1. Authenticatie with username and password
client = boto3.client("cognito-idp", <region>)
response = client.admin_initiate_auth(
    UserPoolId=user_pool_id,
    ClientId=app_client_id,
    AuthFlow='ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH',
    AuthParameters={
        "USERNAME": username,
        "PASSWORD": password
    })
auth_result = response['AuthenticationResult']
access_token = auth_result["AccessToken"]


# 2. associate token (i.e. generate QR code for MFA device paing)
response = client.associate_software_token(AccessToken=access_token)
... (generate QR, let user scan QR, let user enter TOTP user_code)
response = client.verify_software_token(AccessToken=access_token, UserCode=user_code)

# 3. set MFA preference for this user
response = client.admin_set_user_mfa_preference(
        UserPoolId=user_pool_id,
        Username=username,
        SoftwareTokenMfaSettings={'Enabled': True, 'PreferredMfa': True})
```

I feel there's a gap in this. Becuase the QR / pairing workflow needs to be completed only once; in subsequent sessions there should be (username, password, TOTP) authentication and no more device pairing.

Question: how do I recognize whether an MFA device pairing is already in place, so we can skip that part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp/client/get_user.html it says below atrribute

> UserMFASettingList (list) –
>
> The MFA options that are activated for the user. The possible values
> in this list are SMS_MFA and SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA.
>
> (string) –

should give you the MFA devices associated with the user.

Comment: Thanks. I must have overlooked it while scanning for the answer in MFA specific functions on Cognito IDP.